# I need to combine jpages with sorting javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jpage (http://luis-almeida.github.io/jPages/js/jPages.js) to do a pagination for my webpage. I like to sort the element before it goes to pagination.

I use "timestamp" to sort the order, `23, 22, 21, 20.....` and so on.

but my current code only rearrange the items in the same page. example:

1. page 1 : `32, 23, 21, 20....`
2. page 2: `45, 21, 19, 16....`

and so on.

How can i make it sort the order before paginate, so i can get the result of:

1. page 1 : `45, 32, 23, 21, 21....`
2. page 2: `20, 19, 16....`

https://jsfiddle.net/salyyy/zvyhbd8t/15/

```
<div id="itemContainer">  

<li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4" timestamp="3">
                this is test1
            </li>

      <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4" timestamp="38">
                this is test2
            </li>

      <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4" timestamp="11">
                this is test3
            </li>

      ....

      </div>

      <div class="holder"></div>
```

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {

    /* initiate plugin */
    $("div.holder").jPages({
      containerID: "itemContainer",
      minHeight: false,
      perPage:12,
      callback    : function( pages, items ){
        $("#itemContainer").each(function(){
            $(this).find('li').sort(function(a, b) {
            var count = 0;
                // convert to integers from strings
            a = parseInt($(a).attr("timestamp"), 10);
            b = parseInt($(b).attr("timestamp"), 10);
            count += 2;
            // compare
            if(a < b) {
                return 1;
            } else if(a > b) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
            }).appendTo(this);
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Your fiddle does not work. If you open the console you can see why

Comment: my code won't run, how should i fix it? the code is working on my computer, but i can't seem to make it work on jsfiddle. i already include the jpages.js, still no luck.

Comment: Do you want to sort in acceding order or descending order ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callback function execute after pagination therefore you need to sort before pagination and update DOM,

```
 $("#itemContainer").html(
       $("#itemContainer").children("li").sort(function (a, b) {

         a = parseInt($(a).attr("timestamp"), 10);
         b = parseInt($(b).attr("timestamp"), 10);

          return b - a
       });
    );
```

Then apply pagination,

```
$("div.holder").jPages({
    containerID: "itemContainer",
    minHeight: false,
    perPage:12
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u1b08nr7/

Comment: i am not sure why, the code is worked fine in computer, i can't make it work in jsfiddle. all the files has included.

Comment: You've included github files that is the fiddle problem, you can see working example https://jsfiddle.net/xL7b0k4e/2/ ignore the top part of JavaScript section

Comment: thanks, casper. your code worked. I can now arrange the item in sequence.